# Best bugzilla desktop client

Tags: bug-tracking

We've just started to used bugzilla and I found the web interface quite slow and not user-friendly.

I'm wondering if anyone have a suggestion for a client desktop or a browser add-on running under windows.

I found the following page: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons
Which one of these clients (or any other) is the best ?  Any other suggestions ?

I already tried Deskzilla Lite, which seem pretty good. However, there is a lot of field (edit bug) that we don't use (i.e. hardware, os, url, depends on, etc). Is there a desktop client that allow to remove and customize the field used in the bug entry form? On this one, please do not answer I can customize the bugzilla templates, we don't want to use the web interface anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on your Bugzilla Version. Since I updated to 4.0 I've got no alternative to Deskzilla since MyZilla is not running anymore. LiveProject looks pretty neat but I never tested it, so... Deskzilla lite. :/

Comment: I agree. After I post my question, I tried 2-3 desktop client and I adopted deskzilla lite. The only thing: deskzilla lite is limited to 1000 bugs. After that, you have to buy the pro version.